# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 28, 28)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am doing an AI with an interface, using Tensorflow and Flask. I have the following code hosted on PythonAnywhere:

```
@app.route('/output', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def processing():
    if request.args.get('sample'):
        image = Image.open(f'/home/ainum/web/static/samples/{request.args.get("sample")}.jpg')
        filename = f'/home/ainum/web/static/samples/{request.args.get("sample")}.jpg'

    else:
        img = request.files['img']
        name, extension = img.filename.split('.')
        filename = name + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S") + '.' + extension
        img.save('/home/ainum/web/inputs/' + filename)
        image = Image.open('/home/ainum/web/inputs/' + filename)

    model = load_model('/home/ainum/web/model_fmr_all.h5')
    img_width, img_height = Image.HAMMING, Image.HAMMING

    img = image.resize((28, 28), 1)
    img = img.convert('L')
    image = np.array(img, dtype='float64') / 255.

    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    pred = model.predict(image)

    return render_template('res.html', res=str(pred))
```

The error I get when I upload an image is:

```
**NO MATCH**
2022-01-28 08:36:09,018: Exception on /output [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2051, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1501, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1485, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ainum/web/app.py", line 38, in processing
    pred = model.predict(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1629, in predict
    tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 726, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3206, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:
**NO MATCH**
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1478 predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1468 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1461 run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1434 predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:223 assert_input_compatibility
        str(tuple(shape)))
**NO MATCH**
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 28, 28)
**NO MATCH**
```

On the other hand, on localhost everything is correct. Can you explain me this, please? I absolutely don't know AI; the code is not mine; I'm just creating the interface.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you reshape your image to be 4D, you should be good to go. So, after `image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)`, just run `image = image.reshape(image.shape + (1,))`:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.random((28, 28))
image = np.array(img, dtype='float64') / 255.
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
image = image.reshape(image.shape + (1,))
```

Comment: Yes, that works alright, thanks a lot!